# Incorrect reflection in Index part

Tags: indexing

I have the next defined command:

```
\def\underscore{\_\nobreak\hfil\protect\penalty0\hfilneg}
```

Then I want to set some text that usese my command into index:

```
\index{Items! New\underscore\Item}
```

I get incorrect reflection in Index part of my document:

Items

```
   M Item
```

I cannot understand what I do wrong?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It is considered a lot better to put in some code that will compile, as it makes it a lot easier for us to copy it into our text editor and work with it, and see exactly what it is you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably need to put `\protect` before `\underscore` in the `\index` entry.

commands are expanded when written out to the `.idx` file, and since the expansion of `\underscore` contains an `@` sign, it won't behave properly when it's read back in.  the `\protect` ensures that the protected command goes into the `.idx` file as a literal, and will remain so when converted to the `.ind` file to be used by (la)tex to produce the index.